# Updating R on Mac

Tags: r, macos

I'm on MacOS 10.14.6 and I'm looking to update R from version 3.4.0 to 4.0.2. I have two questions:

1. Is it necessary for me to also install Xcode 10.1 and GNU Fortran 8.2? I'm not clear from the notes on the CRAN site whether it's necessary for downloading new packages, updating existing packages, etc.
2. Is there anything that I should do about the previous version of R once 4.0.2 is installed? Does anything need to be deleted or overwritten?

Comment: have you tried installing from the `.pkg` available on cran.r-project.org? this link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-4.0.2.pkg

Comment: just a small word of caution that a major version bump (3 to 4) is likely to cause some disruption to your personal package library. there are some things you can do to smooth this transition but I think my best recommendation is to reinstall any packages you need (this is a way to combat "library bloat" and slim down on packages that you never use)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I haven't tried installing yet. I held off when I saw the note about needing Xcode 10.1 and Fortran 8.2 to compile R packages from sources. Should I download those two items first?

Thanks for the tip about the jump from version 3 to 4. So you would simply reinstall packages by using code like `install.packages("ggplot2")`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just go ahead and install the new R version, if it requires Xcode, then install it. As long as you keep your .r files safe and if something doesn’t work you can always reinstall the older version, if you do have version concerns, get the exact versions of the packages you have installed and save those in case a dependency does break